# Would it be possible to warn OP that a question is being answered to avoid deletion?

Tags: feature-request, status-deferred, answers, deleted-questions

A question was deleted just before I posted my answer. In this case, this is a pity because:

1. the user might not come back and,
2. the comment could have misled him (in my opinion, the answer in the comment was wrong).

This is also very frustrating (I had already written 2 paragraphs, it's a waste of time).

I don't know how undelete works, and maybe another solution is to post the question myself, but this is a "long" process in any case. **It would be nice that the deletion of a question is blocked when someone is answering (or writing a comment)**. Maybe, as a general feature, there could be a signal that shows that someone is writing an answer to a question (this can help to avoid two people writing the same answer at the same time).

Answer (score 8):

I can understand your frustration because I know it has happened to me on occasion too.

However, to get something implemented along those lines would need a convincing argument to be made to Meta Stack Exchange rather than Meta GIS SE and it looks like that has already been proposed there:

- [Prevent Questions From Deleted When Someone is Submitting an Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/95902/prevent-questions-from-deleted-when-someone-is-submitting-an-answer) which looks like it would appreciate an upvote
- [Answer question, hit submit and seeing "sorry, this question has been deleted"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/73200/answer-question-hit-submit-and-seeing-sorry-this-question-has-been-deleted?rq=1)

Comment: upvoted I have.

Answer (score 7):

There is an avenue which doesn't rely on our kind overlords at Stack Exchange to implement a deletion warning or lock on questions. If you have spent time and attention crafting a good answer that is worth sharing and keeping for posterity and those that come after: ask the question yourself!

(It would be worth spending time looking for related older questions your good answer could be adapted to; might be less work re-writing to a different angle than crafting a good question as well as the good answer.)

Comment: thank you for your input. I understand that it is a wide issue and thanks to @Polygeo I could see some discussion on the topic (discovering SE meta). There seem to be a lot of arguments against this new feature, and most are linked with the "speed" of stackoverflow (answers/votes within 15 minute don't give time to reconsider a question).

Comment: However, in my case the frustration is not the main concern. The problem is that a new user has probably been misleaded by a comment, and this could have been avoided if he had not deleted is question. Asking the question myself, in this case, would seem a bit strange because of the misunderstanding of some concept in the question.

Comment: @radouxju, ahh, thanks for the clarification. I thought you were lamenting the answerer's lost effort once the target disappeared. I don't have any suggestions about how to alleviate the OP's confusion over comments.